# Not allowed to work for company?

Tags: hiring

Can a potential employee tell me they are not "allowed" to hire me? I have no criminal record, was born and raised in US, worked part time for the employer with positive feedback, went back to reapply for a different part time position I was told they weren't allowed to hire me....... Fair?

Comment: I assume you mean "potential employer" not "potential employee".  Did they explain what the problem was?  There is a world of difference between "we're in a hiring freeze right now", "we're using eVerify now and you are incorrectly getting flagged as ineligible to work in the country", "there is a note in your personnel file that says you are not eligible for rehire", and any number of other possible problems.

Comment: Depends on what they mean by "not allowed."

Comment: Did you work somewhere previously where a non-compete clause or similar agreement would make the new company uncomfortable hiring you?

Comment: If they decided to hire someone else instead, then it may be true that they are not allowed to hire you (as well). In general you can't expect helpful feedback from a company when your application ends up being turned down.

Comment: And get the notion of fair out of your vocabulary and mindset. Life isn't fair not for anyone. Every single person defines it differently and what is fair to you is totally unfair to a someone else. You will be a lot happier when you stop thinking everything should be fair. Hiring you, for instance, can be seen as unfair to the 200 other applicants.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that the typical reason for this is due to budget constraints.
They may be over budget, or have no budget to hire additional people.

So, even if he would hire you, he cannot because the business cannot afford to pay you. (Which may or may not be true.)

Answer (score 4):

A potential employer can tell you pretty much anything they want. The fact that you have a bunch of desirable traits etc,. doesn't force anyone to give you a job.

In this instance reading between the lines, it's as if the potential employer was instructed by someone higher up not to employ you the individual. If this is the case, then the potential employer can't hire you. There's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

You might ask why not. "Not allowed to hire you" could mean that they believe you are an illegal alien, that you are a convicted sex offender and their office is near a school, etc. But it can also mean lots of things having nothing to do with the law. Like a hiring freeze was just imposed, or the person who is speaking to you wants to hire you but someone else in the company said no, or ... lots of things. You say you used to work there, quit, and are now applying for a new position? Some companies have policies against that.

Or it could mean nothing at all. It could be they just don't want to hire you and this person didn't want to say that.

You could ask, and maybe the information would be useful to you. But for the most part, if a company doesn't want to hire you, there's little to be gained by badgering them for reasons. You are very unlikely to succeed in arguing them into changing their minds. Go look for another job somewhere else.

I guess if you asked and the reason really was some legal constraint and it wasn't true, like they said they couldn't hire you because you are a convicted felon and you're not, there'd be a point in challenging that.

Comment: Also, some companies have policies against hiring the same person a second time within a certain time period. In my experience, it's usually to prevent managers from hiring a contractor over and over to do a job that should be a full time position. When I worked a Kodak, some of the folks there would take early retirement, then get hired back to do their old jobs as contractors - that ended pretty quickly and resulted in a lot of folks that managers were "not allowed to hire".

Comment: @ColleenV Yeah, I was trying to refer to such policies in my comment about quitting and coming back. I used to work for a company that had a policy that if you quit and came back, your salary could not be more than when you left. Maybe they had people using job hopping as a tactic to increase their salary -- get a raise when you leave, get another when you come back. But it seemed a little simple-minded to me